# File encodings with ruby

Tags: ruby, file-encodings

I'm  having a bit problems with file encodings.

I'm receiving a url-encoded string like "sometext%C3%B3+more+%26+andmore", unescape it, process the data, and save it with windows-1252 encoding.

The conversions are these:

```
irb(main) >> value
=> "sometext%C3%B3+more+%26+andmore"
irb(main) >> CGI::unescape(value)
=> "sometext\303\263 more & andmore"
irb(main) >> #Some code and saved into a file using open(filename, "w:WINDOWS-1252")
irb(main) >> # result in the file:
=> sometextĂ³ more & andmore
```

And the result should be `sometextó more & andmore`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoding support has been added to Ruby 1.9, so the following code is from Ruby 1.9.1:

```
require 'cgi'
#=> true
s = "sometext%C3%B3+more+%26+andmore"
#=> "sometext%C3%B3+more+%26+andmore"
t = CGI::unescape s
#=> "sometext\xC3\xB3 more & andmore"
t.force_encoding 'utf-8' # telling Ruby that the string is UTF-8 encoded
#=> "sometextó more & andmore"
t.encode! 'windows-1252' # changing encoding to windows-1252
#=> "sometext? more & andmore"
# here you do whatever you want to do with windows-1252 encoded string
```

[Here](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) you have lots of informations on Ruby and encodings.

PS. Ruby 1.8.7 doesn't have built-in support for encodings, so you have to use some external library for conversion, for example [iconv](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Iconv.html):

```
require 'iconv'
#=> true
require 'cgi'
#=> true
s = "sometext%C3%B3+more+%26+andmore"
#=> "sometext%C3%B3+more+%26+andmore"
t = CGI::unescape s
#=> "sometext\303\263 more & andmore"
Iconv.conv 'windows-1252', 'utf-8', t
#=> "sometext\363 more & andmore"
# \363 is ó in windows-1252 encoding
```

Comment: I didn't say anything, but I need a solution using Ruby 1.8.7

(But thanks :))

Comment: I have some problems with my input, but this works. 

Thank you!